# %40 converted into @ on Get

Tags: encoding, url-encoding

I am passing my variables as follows to url using GET method

```
http://www.mysite.com/demo.php?sid=123121&email_id=stevemartin144%40gmail.com
```

& when i print $_GET on demo.php it displays parameters as follows:

```
email_id    stevemartin144@gmail.com
sid 123121
```

instead of above output i want parameters as i passed

```
email_id    stevemartin144%40gmail.com
sid 123121
```

I don't want to convert %40 into @

please suggest me solution on this

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

"%40" in a URL *means* "@". If you want a "%" to *mean* "%", you need to URL encode it to "%25".

URL encoding is just a transport encoding. If you feed in "@", its transport encoded version is "%40", but the recipient will get "@" again. If you want to feed in "%40" and have the recipient receive "%40", you need to URL encode it to "%2540".

If the recipient correctly receives "@" but you want to use the URL encoded version for whatever reason, you can also have the recipient urlencode it again.

Answer (score 0):

**Notes:**

**Online Converter:**

Replace special characters with its equivalent hexadecimal unicode. 
For a list of unicodes refer the website [https://unicode-table.com](http://unicodelookup.com) (or) [http://unicodelookup.com](https://unicode-table.com)

**Local Converter using Python:**

**Reference:** conversion of password "p@s#w:E" to unicode will be as follows,

```
@ = %40
$ = %24
# = %23
: = %3A
p@s#w:E = p%40s%23w%3AE
```

**Input:**

```
[root@localhost ~]# python -c "import sys, urllib as enc; print enc.quote_plus(sys.argv[1])" "p@s#w:E"
```

**Output:**

```
p%40s%23w%3AE
```